# iCloud password reset

Tags: itunes, icloud, backup, iphone, password

How do I change the Apple iCloud password that is synched to a computer no longer available to me?
I am trying to backup my contacts to my new computer.  I have loaded the latest iTunes application on my notebook.  updates my iPhone 4S iOS8.  The mobile icon doesn't appear in iTunes.  The folder shows up in the drive tree.

So I am trying to backup everything to an iCloud account however I can't access it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have the password for an iCloud account, and also do not have the means to reset it via [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com) page, then you can't do anything with that iCloud account.

Also, it seems you have a couple of issues: iTunes not recognising your iPhone?

PD: Why would you want to backup everything to an iCloud account you can no longer access?